# dllexport class template instances (specializations), reducing compilation time for header-only template libraries

Tags: c++, dll, class-template, template-instantiation, compilation-time

Is it possible to export some of the class template instances, while leaving to a library's user the ability of generating other specializations of a given class template (when compiling the executable).

Given I have a public header

```
// public.h
#pragma once

#ifndef DLL_BUILD
#define API __declspec(dllimport)
#else 
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif // !DLL_BUILD

#include <type_traits>


// dummy to generate .lib
struct API dummy
{
    void be_dummy();
};



template <class T>
struct Foo
{
    static T Sum(T a, T b)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_fundamental_v<T>);
        return a + b;
    }
};
```

With this way of declaring class template `Foo` every instantiation will happen inside the user's executable.

However, if I define `Foo` as `dllexport/dllimport` using `API` macro, every specialization of `Foo` which has not been explicitly instantiated inside the dll, will fail to link.

```
// impl.cpp - dll

#include "public.h"


void dummy::be_dummy()
{
    volatile int a = 0;
    return;
}

template API struct Foo<int>;


///////////////////////////////////////////
// main.cpp - executable

#include "public.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    dummy().be_dummy();

    // std::cout << Foo<double>().Sum(4.12, 3.18) << std::endl; // Unresolved external symbol

    std::cout << Foo<int>().Sum(60, 9) << std::endl; // executed within the dll

    return 0;
}
```

So, is it possible to force the compiler to link against an existing class template instance when one has been exported, and to generate another that has not.

**UPDATE**

I found a solution, see my answer below.
I leave the old update just in case anybody will find such usage of SFINAE helpful.

---

**UPDATE OLD**

I found one cumbersome solution involving SFINAE, but it results in defining a class template twice, therefore is very error prone. I don't know if it can be wrapped up with macro in a manner that will make it possible to write it only once.

```
// public.h
#pragma once

#ifndef DLL_BUILD
#define API __declspec(dllimport)
#else 
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif // !DLL_BUILD

#include <type_traits>

namespace templ_export
{
    template <class T>
    struct is_exported : std::false_type {};

    // this can be placed to a separated header (i.e. Exported.hpp)
    template <> struct is_exported<int> : std::true_type {};

    template <class T>
    struct API FooExported
    {
        static T Sum(T a, T b)
        {
            //static_assert(std::is_fundamental_v<T>);
            return a + b;
        }
    };

    template <class T>
    struct FooNotExported
    {
        static T Sum(T a, T b)
        {
            //static_assert(std::is_fundamental_v<T>);
            return a + b;
        }
    };


    template <class T, bool = templ_export::is_exported<T>()>
    struct GetFooExported
    {
        using type = FooNotExported<T>;
    };

    template <class T>
    struct GetFooExported<T, true>
    {
        using type = FooExported<T>;
    };
}


template <class T>
using Foo = typename templ_export::GetFooExported<T>::type;


/////////////////////////////////
// impl.cpp

#include "public.h"


void dummy::be_dummy()
{
    volatile int a = 0;
    return;
}

template struct API templ_export::FooExported<int>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of exporting class template instances.

On Dll creation compiler must think, that `Foo` is defined as dllexport. But while creating an Executable and linking to that Dll, `Foo` class template must not have any `declspec` attributes applied to it. Though we need to declare particular class template instances as `dllimport`.

```
// public.h
#pragma once

#ifndef DLL_BUILD
#define API __declspec(dllimport)
#else 
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif // !DLL_BUILD

// define T_API emplty for library users, hence they will see just 'struct Foo'
#ifndef T_API
#define T_API
#endif

#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct T_API Foo
{
    static T Sum(T a, T b)
    {
        //static_assert(std::is_fundamental_v<T>);
        return a + b;
    }
};
```

```
// impl.cpp
// Compile with DLL_BUILD defined

// define T_API for library build
#define T_API __declspec(dllexport)

#include "public.h"


void dummy::be_dummy()
{
    volatile int a = 0;
    return;
}

// instantiating class template 
template struct T_API Foo<int>;
```

For executable:

```
// Exported.h
// this header needs to be shipped alongside with public.h and included after
#pragma once

// declare template instance as imported
template struct __declspec(dllimport) Foo<int>;
```

```
// main.cpp 
// Executable linked to library

#include "public.h"
#include "Exported.h"



int main()
{
    dummy().be_dummy();

    // Sum is called from Executable
    std::cout << Foo<double>().Sum(4.12, 3.18) << std::endl;

    // Sum is called from Dll
    std::cout << Foo<int>().Sum(60, 9) << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

I consider this approach to be useful for header-only template libraries. Like precompiled headers, dll with class template instances will reduce compilation time.